# Getting an error saying there's an unknown table in the field list when that table exists

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to output the amount of discount given to a customer by finding the difference, but I keep getting `Error #1109 Unknown table 'item' in field list` when I do have a table named `item` in my current DB.

I'm using this query:

```
SELECT orderpay.orderid , cust.name , (orderpay.totalpay - actualCost) as `discount amount`
FROM cust , orderpay , tran , item, 
  (SELECT sum(item.unitprice * tran.quantity) ) as actualCost
WHERE item.itemid = tran.itemid AND (orderpay.totalpay - actualCost) > 0
GROUP BY item.itemid
```

Here are my table structures:

```
cust
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| custid  | int(5)      | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| name    | varchar(22) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| email   | varchar(33) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| address | varchar(29) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| city    | varchar(21) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| country | varchar(14) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

item
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| itemid    | int(5)       | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| name      | varchar(94)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| unitprice | decimal(6,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| cat       | varchar(12)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

orderpay
+----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| orderid  | int(5)        | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| date     | varchar(10)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| custid   | int(5)        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| cardnum  | varchar(25)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| cardtype | varchar(25)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| totalpay | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

tran 
+----------+--------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type   | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+--------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| orderid  | int(5) | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| itemid   | int(5) | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| quantity | int(2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+--------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Are there multiple orders and you want to find the total across all orders, or are you trying to fing the discount per order?

Comment: trying to get the customer name, ids and the discount amount on all orders that have any type of discount

Comment: SELECT SUM(item.unitprice * tran.quantity) ) This is not a query

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing your query like below

```
SELECT *, 
(totalpay - computed_price) as `discount amount`
FROM 
(
SELECT orderpay.orderid , 
cust.name ,
orderpay.totalpay , 
sum(item.unitprice * `tran`.quantity) as computed_price     
FROM cust JOIN `tran` ON item.itemid = tran.itemid
JOIN orderpay ON cust.some_column = orderpay.some_column      
JOIN item ON  cust.some_column = item.some_column      
GROUP BY item.itemid
) tab
WHERE (totalpay - computed_price) > 0
```

Comment: I do not think you can do it without a subquery.

Comment: Not that kind of subquery :), i will give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select totalpaid.custid, (totalprices.total - totalpaid.total) as `discount` FROM 
(
     SELECT sum(totalpay) as total, custid 
     FROM orderpay 
     GROUP BY custid
) as totalpaid JOIN 
(
     SELECT sum(item.unitprice * tran.quantity) as total, orderpay.custid 
     FROM orderpay JOIN tran ON orderpay.orderid=tran.orderid JOIN item ON tran.itemid item.itemid
     GROUP BY orderpay.custid
) as totalprices ON totalpaid.custid = orderpay.custid
```

As a side note, you should not use this to calculate the total as if prices changed (and they do change in time) you calculation will be all messed up. Instead you should remember the discount for each order when you create it.

VERY IMPORTANT
Also it scares me that you have a field called cardnum  | varchar(25) you should never ever keep the CC numbers.

Comment: VERY GOOD POINT ABOUT in-the-clear credit card number storage!